# Why does my Materialized View take much longer to run the first time it is called after a refresh?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres materialized view that gets refreshed every night - a fairly large dataset. The first time someone tries to run it after a refresh, the query takes 9-10 minutes. After that, queries return in their usual 1-2 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM MyMaterializedView
WHERE response_time BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-02-01'
AND property_id = 123
```

...and there is an index on the Materialized View for the response_time and property_id columns.

My question is - is it normal for the initial running of a materialized view to take so much longer, and is there a way to handle this in the refresh to prevent the initial long-running query?

Comment: You need an incremental refresh or lazy loading

Comment: Run [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) on the materialized view immediately after the `REFRESH`?

Comment: Probably the data has been driven out of cache.  Rather than guessing, you can turn track_io_timing on, do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possible reasons:

- the data are not cached the first time you query the materialized view
- the first query has to set the “hint bits” on all the rows it selects

You should set `track_io_timing = on` and run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...` on your query to know for sure. If it is the first problem, you will see lots of `buffers read` and a high I/O time, in the second case you'll see lots of `buffers dirtied` or `buffers written`.